# Redis Rust Cluster Mode Broken pipe Error

Tags: rust, redis, pipe, cluster-computing

I use redis crate of rust. I am using cluster mode and continuously trying to get a certain key using an infinite loop. However, when I kill the master node that stores that key, the program encounters "Broken pipe (os error 32)" and crashes.

I expect it to continue running and get the key from the new master (previous slave of the killed master).

```
use std::error::Error;
use redis::Commands;
use redis::cluster::ClusterClient;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box> {

let nodes = vec!["redis://127.0.0.1:7000/","redis://127.0.0.1:7001/", "redis://127.0.0.1:7002/","redis://127.0.0.1:7003/", "redis://127.0.0.1:7004/", "redis://127.0.0.1:7005/"];
let client = ClusterClient::new(nodes)?;
let mut con = client.get_connection()?;


loop {
let a : String  =con.get("test")?;
}


Ok(())
}
```

Then I docker kill the master node of the key "test",
the error I am getting is that

Error occurred: Broken pipe (os error 32)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).